# Visual C++ - Writing doubles and integers to binary files

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm reading info from one text file, then outputting it to a bin file. I got the name to write properly, but the integer and doubles do not work properly. Disregard the system("pause"), they are so I can check my outputs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct SaleSlip{
    char name[20];
    int prodID;
    double value;
};

void main(){

    fstream slips, binslip;
    SaleSlip sales[17];
    binslip.open("SaleSlips.bin", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);
    slips.open("SaleSlips.txt", ios::in);
    if(slips.eof()){
        cout << "Cannot open file - SaleSlips.txt"<< endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(2);
    }
    int i = 0;
    while(!slips.eof()){
        slips >> sales[i].name;
        slips.ignore(80, ' ');
        slips >> sales[i].prodID;
        slips.ignore(80, ' ');
        slips >> sales[i].value;
        slips.ignore(80, '\n');
        cout << sales[i].name;
        cout << sales[i].prodID;
        cout << sales[i].value << endl;

        binslip.write((const char *)&sales[i].name, sizeof(sales[i].name));
        binslip.write((const char *)&sales[i].prodID, sizeof(sales[i].prodID));
        binslip.write((const char *)&sales[i].value, sizeof(sales[i].value));
        i++;
    }
    slips.close();
    binslip.close();
    system("pause");
}
```

SaleSlips.txt has one line per item of the array so "Ryan 2 1400.52" is one line. Ryan is interpreted correctly, but when I read back in from the binary it isn't right, nor is it when I check it in textpad.

Comment: If you want to "check your outputs" you can try adding `std::cin.get()` just before your exit statements (and before `main` returns). Your program will prompt for some input, and you can just press enter when you want it to close.

Comment: If you have two lines does the name work for both lines or is Ryan the only thing that works?  

Are the values in `sales[i].prodID` when you output them?
also why is it void main()?

Comment: Yeah I have 17 lines, and all the names work properly. when i output sales[i].prodID in main i get the correct values. I made main void because I was moving stuff around and didn't want to mess with the return, which i tend to forget about.

Comment: Just place the return statement at the very end of the function, and make sure you never write any code below it.

Answer (score 2):

`binslip.write` is an [UnformattedOutputFunction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UnformattedOutputFunction). There is formatted and unformatted input/output. When you use unformatted output, you are writing raw bytes to the file. There is no interpretation as to what the bytes actually represent.

When you wrote to SalesSlips.bin, you wrote characters followed by numbers (rather, what you thought would be numbers). When you tried to examine SalesSlips.bin, the computer read text characters, and was expecting the rest of the file to be text, but it wasn't. Numbers are represented differently then characters. Even if you were to just deal with numbers alone, integral and floating point values are represented differently in binary. It may be a bit much for you to absorb right now, but the gist of it is you need to use a [FormattedOutputFunction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/FormattedOutputFunction). This will perform the internal conversions necessary for you to output your data properly.

Imagine you have a number, lets say, 50. That number is meaningless without units that describe what 50 represents. 50 seconds? 50 feet? 50 states? You can think of `binslip.write` as just writing 50, and when you try to read the file later, all you see is 50, and you don't understand what it was supposed to represent, which is why it looks like gibberish to you.

To fix your code you need to replace the `binslip.write` lines with this:

`binslip << sales[i].name << sales[i].prodID << sales[i].value;`

In this case, `operator<<` behaves as a `FormattedOutputFunction`, so when you write SaleSlips.bin, you can open it in a text editor and view `Ryan 2 1400.52` like you expected.

Comment: I'm looking at it in Hex, that's how I've been checking it. It has the hex there but then also it's counterpart in text. I don't need it to re-output it, but I wanted to check it so that it is right. I don't know if that would change your answer or not.

Comment: If you use `binslip <<`, your numbers will be written to the file differently. Your output file isn't correct. You'll have to re-output it if you want to see the proper output. Try it and see how the data changes.

Comment: I redid it with each line edited to binslip << sales[i]----, but it only helped output the value, it still doesn't show the integer value for prodID

Answer (score 1):

While reading and writing in BINARY mode, you are not expected to read the data in any text editor. It simply serves no purpose. If you want to read it in a text editor, recommendation is to use NORMAL mode.

Anyways, if you don't bother about viewing your BINARY data in a text editor, you could use the following lines to Read and write binary file:

```
while(!slips.eof())
{
    slips >> sales[i].name;
    slips.ignore(80, ' ');
    slips >> sales[i].prodID;
    slips.ignore(80, ' ');
    slips >> sales[i].value;
    slips.ignore(80, '\n');
    cout << sales[i].name;
    cout << sales[i].prodID;
    cout << sales[i].value << endl;

    //// WRITE THE STRUCTURE AT ONCE
    binslip.write((const char *)&sales[i], sizeof(sales[i]));
    i++;
}
binslip.flush();
binslip.close();

//// OPEN UP THE FILE IN READ MODE
binslip.open("SaleSlips.bin", ios::in | ios::binary );
SaleSlip sale;
//// READ UP THE COMPLETE STRUCTURE
binslip.read((char *)&sale, sizeof(sale));
//// PRINT IT.
cout<<sale.name;
cout<<sale.prodID;
cout<<sale.value;
```

Comment: welcome.... Please Don't forget to mark the posts you find suitable as answers :)